# Query has been changed in mysql Binlog - Load data query

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysqlbinlog

I had run the below mysql query in master server

```
load data local infile '/tmp/LRD.csv'
into table **offline**.LPLRD_Updates
  fields terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  lines terminated by '\n';
```

but this has been change in binlog as

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/SQL_LOAD_MB-597-0'
INTO TABLE `LPLRD_Updates`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I have mentioned **offline** database in my query but it has changed to default database in binlog .

This creates the problem in replication as default database do not have this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing use db_name; and then load data to the table. Replication breaks or has some documented disadvantages in statement based logging. By the way you cannot really claim data with it on DR site.